# VS 2010 debugging outlook RibbonExtensibility UI xml

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, outlook-addin

When creating a RibbonExtensibility class for, say, adding custom context menu buttons, is there some way in VS to debug whether the XML you are returning in GetCustomUI is actually valid?

For example, if my XML tries to use a non-existent idMso, I'd like VS to inform me of this somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable addin error reporting in Outlook: `File | Options | Advanced | Developers | Show add-in user interface errors`.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx) in MSDN.